# Batch script for sleep/hibernate

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sleep

I would like to write a script in batch that forces the computer to enter 
sleep (s3) and/or hibernate(s4), for a certain amount of time. I couldn't find answer for this question nowhere.

Example:

1. Computer enters sleep state.
2. 30 seconds pass.
3. Computer returns and continues the script.

I managed to use an external program, but after a few cycles of the procedure
the  computer for some reason enters a sleep state for 4,294,966,391 seconds
and only continues the script when turned on manually.

Comment: check [this](http://superuser.com/questions/42124/how-can-i-put-the-computer-to-sleep-from-command-prompt-run-menu)

Comment: @Biffen as I understand it, this question is about putting the computer itself into sleep mode, whereas your duplicate candidate is about sleeping just a particular process - something quite different.

Comment: @Ben Read the question again and yeah, I think you're right. Mea culpa.